# HTML Conditional href

Tags: html, href

I have a folder containing a large number of pdf files. They are named with a code of 3 digits (XXX.pdf). In that same folder, I have a index.html file, which as its name suggests, is an index for navigating in the folder and opening a specific pdf.

As an example, when I search a specific pdf file but I don't know what's the name of the pdf. I only know its title or authors.

- Without that index, I have no solution to find it.
- With the index, the pdf are classified according to authors or titles so I can search within the index and click on the link to open the file. The index contain this line for each pdf file:

```html
<a href="001.pdf"><STRONG>TITLE001</STRONG></a><br /> Author001
```

So, this is the first configuration. I can give the entire folder to a colleague and he can open the index to search for a file as soon as he doesn't change the folder organization because the href link is relative.

Now, I have a second configuration in which I uploaded that folder on a server on a private network. I changed the index.html with the following line:

```html
<a href="http://personal_cloud/001.pdf"><STRONG>TITLE001</STRONG></a><br />Author001
```

In that way if someone search a specific pdf file, he can download the index and when he click on the like in that index, it will download the correct pdf from the server.

BUT, I would like to have both configuration working:

- If my colleague uses a lot that folder, he will maybe prefer to download the entire folder and the index will not work because its not a relative address anymore.
- If my colleague uses it occasionally, he will just download the index and it will work.

Is there any solution to merge both solution and to have a conditional href attribute ?

Allowing to use both configurations. Something like:

```html
if "001.pdf" doesn't exist
   <a href="http://personal_cloud/001.pdf"><STRONG>TITLE001</STRONG></a><br />Author001
else
   <a href="001.pdf"><STRONG>TITLE001</STRONG></a><br />Author001
```

Can someone help me with that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Doubt you will find a way to do that in HTML, how about something with Js ? Do you use JQuery or something ?

Something like that could do it then :

```
$.ajax({
type: 'HEAD',
url: 'http://personal_cloud/001.pdf',
success: function() {
    // here when then file does exist
},  
error: function() {
    // here when then file does not exist
}
});
```

Comment: Well, first thanks for your reply.
I don't have advanced skills in html, Js or JQuery, but I'm trying to improve. In fact, I was looking to a simple way to edit the already existing index.html file, and not to write it entirely again. In fact this is not a project or something I'm really working on. It's more an improvement of my usage of that file organization system.
If it's not possible never mind I don't want to change completely that.
Anyway, I'll try to have a look at Js and JQuery.